# Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 - Not being able to connect to Wifi

Tags: networking, broadcom

I posted the below yesterday, got an update that there is an extensive answer here:
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

## My issue is that in step 1, I get:
14e4:4311 rev2 and is does not appear in the table in the next step.
There is 14e4:4311 rev1 but not rev2.
Can you pls add it to the relevant table?
thank you.

just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on HP Pavillion dv6000 notebook.
After installation completed, tried to browse through firefox and seeing Im not connected.

Explored some relevant questions, and I do know Ubuntu can see my device as when going to terminal and typing command:

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network
```

Getting the info. that it is Broadcomm
Here is exactly what I get:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4311 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [103c:1374]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at f4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: ssb
```

Not sure if I understand correctly but now I need to get a firmware install package and then driver both for Linux/Ubuntu for Broadcomm 4311 but this is where I go lost as when looking those, found some install package on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/b43-fwcutter but there were many options there and I was not sure if Im on the right path of maybe there is a much simpler way or Im not reading the issue correctly.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Connect to internet using your phone and install the driver by `sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer`

Comment: Thank you just did that and it resolve the issue. After installation of above and restart wifi is now connecting thank you!